# table cells added programmatically are not covered by opaque fixed title bar when scrolled

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed title bar with a high z-index that covers every element on the page when they're scrolled up except for the contents of table cells that were created programmatically.
What are the attributes or styles I need to set so the table cells willbe hidden behind the title bar?
I tried to post an image of how it looks but I need 10 reputation for that :-(
Thanks.

Comment: did you try putting z-index lower than the value of the z-index in your title bar?

Comment: I haven't defined z-index for the table cells but since the z-index for title bar is set to 10000, wouldn't that serve the same purpose? I will try that anyway and thanks for the suggestion. 
Incidentally, what is the default value for z-index if one is not specifically defined?

Comment: defining lower z-index did not make any difference.

Comment: can you post your code? so that we can see if what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like encapsulating the cell values inside Html.Encode is what was needed. I was initially using

`<td>
<%= someParameter%><br />
</td>`

but once I changed it to

`<td>
<%= Html.Encode(someParameter)%><br />
</td>`

it worked like a charm. If anyone knows why that is the case, I would appreciate your comments.